# How to set environment variable from response which includes # and -

Tags: javascript, postman

How can i set an environment variable from this type of response? I know how to set them but i cant figure out what to do when the parameter includes `#` and `-` in the naming. Postman complains about this.

I tried to set it from the parent object and trim the saved variable, but this didnt work.

```
enter jsonData.Drawing.File.forEach(function(file){ 
    postman.setEnvironmentVariable("URLs", file.FileURL.... <what do i do here?);         
});
```

Here is the response and the yellow is what im trying to set.

[This is the response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tI4JU.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Accessing variables like `#cdata-section` is done through JavaScript syntax like this: `file.FileURL["#cdata-section"]`.

You cant access it like this: `file.FileURL.#cdata-section`, because `#` is invalid for object accessing.

Also `-` is perfectly fine to use in normal variables, so something like this: `file.FileURL.another-section`, would be valid.

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to get all the `urls` in the `File` array, you could do something like this to loop through the array, grab the url values and add them to a new `fileURLs` array, before storing them to an environment variable.

```
let fileURLs = []

_.each(pm.response.json().Drawing.File, (file) => { 
    fileURLs.push(file.FileURL["#cdata-section"])
});

pm.environment.set("fileURLs", JSON.stringify(fileURLs));
```

It looks like you're looping over the array but it would only store the last URL as the variable, that's cool if you have only one to grab each time but if you have multiple objects, you might miss some of those values :)

Comment: Hello Danny, yes that is exactly what i did :) Just didnt include all of the code.But thanks for the tips :)